# Querying XML tag in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table Student with a column studentStateinfo which consist of XML value as below.

```
<params xmlns="">
  <OldStudentID>1aedghe1d8ef</OldStudentID>
</params>
```

Now when I query this table Student I only want to check whether studentStateinfo column have an XML data with tag `<OldStudentID>`

Answer (score 1):

Use the [exist() Method (xml Data Type)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/exist-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15)

Example using a variable, you should change that to a column instead.

```
declare @X xml = '
<params xmlns="">
  <OldStudentID>1aedghe1d8ef</OldStudentID>
</params>';

select @X.exist('/params/OldStudentID');
```